# How can I insert/update JSON array in Mongoose?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a post method in an API that `req.body` contains JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "art": "A",
        "count": "20",
        "name": "name1",
        "ean": "802.0079.127",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "A"
    },
    {
        "art": "A",
        "count": "10",
        "name": "name2",
        "ean": "657.7406.559",
        "marker": "null",
        "stammkost": "A"
    }
]
```

How can I insert or update Mongoose in Node? Is there any way to bulk insert this JSON array?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at `insertMany()` http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

You can add a JSON array, and Mongoose will add it to its collection.

Comment: i get this erorr: `insertMany is not a function`, could you help me by complete example please ?

Comment: Say you have the model `Table` defined with Mongoose. You want to insert an array of tables, you do as follow: `Table.insertMany(your_JSON_array).then(doc => { // something... })`.